# Are Azure DevOps Bugs, Tasks, User Stories field values able to be calculated instead of manual data entry?

Tags: plugins, azure-devops, devops, calculated-field

For example, take the value of two numeric fields, and populate a 3rd field based on the sum  of the first two fields?  Is this possible with Azure "out of the box" or using a 3rd party plug in?

Comment: Azure DevOps is a open Ecosystem. With the all mighty [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) you can full fill this task. With a [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) call you can read the data of a workitem, with [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) you can update the data of a workitem. But this calls in a (PowerShell) script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> take the value of two numeric fields, and populate a 3rd field based
>   on the sum of the first two fields

For this issue, I am afraid there is currently no out-of-the-box function in azure devops to achieve it.

As a workaround , we can create a query, list the work items, and then add these three numeric fields to the **column** to display them in the query.

[image]

Then we can export these work items with `Export to CSV` option. Open this `.csv` file in **Excel** and then complete the summation.

[image]

Import the updated `.csv` file into Azure devops.

[image]

Click the `Save items` option to update the work item. Through this method we can batch sum for fields. You could also choose to develop a customized extension for this feature.

[image]

In addition ,you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback to increase priority.